# java access redis throw java.util.NoSuchElementException: Unable to validate object

Tags: java, redis

when I used the java code to operated redis was OK.But  after project run  a few hours when I access redis again project   was throw The following  Exception .

java.util.NoSuchElementException: Unable to validate object
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:506)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:49)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:99)

java code:

Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();

I used a redis-cli.exe clinet to access redis is ok.  What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: ^ That should be part of the question itself, not a comment underneath.  It will be easily missed otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem today, too, I tried to find some solutions, but at last, I just relaunched the redis-server, the problem was solved.

PS: my redis version is 3.2.6